# angularjs- dropdown value should be number not object

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have an array of objects that looks like

```
$scope.pArray = [{id: 0, name: 'bob'}, {id: 1, name: 'jen'}];
```

In my select dropdown, Im using ng-options instead of ng-repeat like so:

```
 <select id="province" name="item" ng-model="obj.name" required
     ng-options="item.id as prov.name for item in pArray track by item.id"></select>
```

Now when I hit the submit button, the value of obj.name is an object instead of the integer (0 or 1). How can I change this so that instead of the object, I get the id?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="emp.name for emp in pArray ">
</select>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);
app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
   $scope.pArray = [{id: 0, name: 'bob'}, {id: 1, name: 'jen'}];
    $scope.getselected = function(selected) {
      alert(selected.id)
    }

  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="dobController">
  <div class="col-md-20">
    <div id="main">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Filter List:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="emp.name for emp in pArray ">
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getselected(selected)">selected</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the the angular docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

You should try:
ng-options="item as item.name for item in pArray track by item.id"

You should try changing the "item.id as" to "item as" since you are using track by item.id. Also, did you mean "item.name" and not "prov.name"

Anyway, that's just quick and hopefully helpful place to start.